# Magento 2: How to display store information in email footer?

Tags: email, email-templates, footer, footer-links, reference

Using magento 2.2.2 with custom theme which inherits from `Magento/blank`.

I am altering the template stored here:

> [Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Email/email/footer.html

I would like to include my store information (telephone number, address etc.) inside the footer programmatically, but I am unsure whether/how I can format a reference to the store information inside the `footer.html` file.

I would also like to include social links, though I'm not sure whether it's best to do this programmatically, using a social plugin, or to hard code the links directly into the email template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are better off hardcoding this in, this is data that doesn't or shouldn't change that often so using a plugin/extension to do this is like using a sledgehammer to crack a wallnut

Comment: Ok thanks.. and there is no way, without a sledgehammer, to retrieve this information as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

This will display the store information in footer of your emails

```
<h2><a href="{{store url=''}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}</a></h2>
        <p class="address">
            <span class="street-line1"> {{config path="general/store_information/street_line1"}} </span>
            <span class="street-line2"> {{config path="general/store_information/street_line2"}}, </span>
            <span class="city"> {{config path="general/store_information/city"}}, </span>
            <span class="region"> {{config path="general/store_information/region_id"}} </span>
            <span class="postcode"> {{config path="general/store_information/postcode"}} </span>
            <span class="phone">
            | <span class="number"> {{config path="general/store_information/phone"}} </span>
            </span>  
        </p>
```